# How to add a column to dataframe with multiindex columns with vlookup function?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i'm trying to figure out how to add a columns from this dataframe:
[image]

To this one:

[image]

As you guys can see, both dataframes have "SPU" column, so data need to be added according to this column(like vlookup function). The problems is the second dataframe have multiindex columns, so things like:

```
pv = pd.merge(dataframe1,dataframe2[['SPU','Adv_per_unit']],on = 'SPU',how='left')
```

is not working.

I was tried to figure it out by myself, by adding:

```
dataframe1['Ads', 'Adv_per_unit'] = dataframe2['Adv_per_unit']
```

but obviously this doesn't solve the problem, as data in 'Adv_per_unit' is not matched with data from dataframe2 because it wasn't merged properly.

p.s. i checked many already existed similar topics on stackoverflow, but didn't found a solution for the case when data need to be added with vlookup function.

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the SPU entries are unique, you could use that column for the index and then run

`dataframe1['Ads', 'Adv_per_unit'] = dataframe2['Adv_per_unit']`

### Edit: expanded answer

To set the SPU as the index, you should run:

```py
dataframe1.set_index("SPU", inplace=True)
dataframe2.set_index("SPU", inplace=True)
```

Comment: Can please explain more detail how to do it